# Chart.js - hide / remove label on second dataset

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, data-analysis

I have a line graph with 2 identical datasets - the only difference is the 2nd dataset utilizes the Chart.js trendline plugin.

How can I only display **only the label for the first dataset** when someone hovers over one of the datapoints? 
So far, I've looked at a lot the documentation and many other questions on StackOverflow and can't seem to find the answer.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure out the answer. There were 86 items in both data sets & the second dataset started at an index of 43. It's a pretty ugly solution, but it works. Add the below in the options section.

```
tooltips: {
    filter: function (tooltipItem, data) {
        var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];                           
        if (tooltipItem.datasetIndex > 42) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```